# Error when changing shell of root user in Solaris 10

Tags: bash, solaris, shell, sh

I can't change my shell for root in Solaris 10. When i change, i can't login again after logout. The error is "no shell".

Comment: What shell are you changing from/to? Are you sure you have the correct path to the shell? Depending on how things are setup you may need to put the full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this issue and I believe the shell binary has to be on the / partition, at least in recovery mode when the other partitions are not mounted.

Answer (score 1):

You probably messed the /etc/passwd file by editing it directly.
What prints `head -1 /etc/passwd | od -c` ?
Shell should be changed by using the `passwd -e` command.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the full path to the shell executable and I believe that appropriate permissions have to also be set.